# Is my calf supposed to hurt while I’m doing the half middle splits?

Tags: flexibility, splits

I started learning the splits 3 months ago and while stretching my right half middle split, my extended leg tends to shift to the side and my calf hurts. I try to keep it straight but it makes my calf hurt even more, I don’t have this problem with my left leg.

What do I do or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In any exercise, its okay to feel some pain when you are doing them. But if you feel some sharp pain whenever you do some particular movement, it is recommended to give it soe rest and try maybe after 1 week

Comment: I wouldn’t exactly say some pain is okay. Any pain may indicate that you’re doing something wrong. Rather, I think Aaryan is referring to some form of discomfort. 
I am not sure what a half middle split is (if you have a photo to show, thats great), but you might want to look out for any compensations you are making due to a lack of mobility or flexibility in other areas.